# Direction to take for google drive api

Tags: google-drive-api

Thank you for those who will be pointing me to the right direction regarding my question. Currently I am trying to incorporate Google-Drive API into a friends website. What he wishes is for those who are members to be able to view others files. For example, lets say student A needs a report to be edited/helped with. Student B will be able to download that person file from student A google drive folder and upload the edited/fixed version to the person.

I'll appreciate any advice on the direction I should be looking into. Thank you for all your advice.

I am using Ruby on Rails for those wondering which programming language.

For any further questions please feel free to ask.

Comment: Big question is whether you want to do this server-side or client-side. You'll need to add more detail on the permission model that you want to achieve. For example, will B be able to overwrite A's file, or will he be cloning, editing and the sending a pull-request (to use GIT parlance)

Comment: Question is too broad. Specifically what problems you had while using the drive api?